# What does ! mean in record definition before field type?

Tags: haskell

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information to the question.

```
data Person =
  Person { firstName  :: !Text
         , lastName   :: !Text
         , age        :: Int
         , likesPizza :: Bool
           } deriving Show
```

The code snippet is token from article [Parsing JSON with Aeson](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json#step-1--define-your-type--collect-your-data).

Aside the question in the title, is there a rule when `!` should be used?
In the example above `!` is used only for `firstName` and `lastName`.

Comment: It is a *bang pattern*. It means that it is evaluated eagerly. So that when you assign it to a `Person` object. The expression tree is evaluated up to WHNF. See [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) for more information.

Comment: That code is really weird. It smells of cargo cult strictness, which a small portion of Haskell users have a real problem with. I'm willing to bet no benchmarking nor semantic analysis went into deciding what fields of that record to make strict.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it's a bang all right, but not a bang pattern. Bang patterns are a GHC extension for using `!` in *patterns* to force things. This is actually standard Report Haskell for making a data constructor strict in a certain argument.

Comment: These are described in [Haskell 98](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) section 4.2.1 under the heading "Strictness Flags".

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281404/241990) has some useful guidelines on when to use them. It is also possible to enable them by default for data structures using the[`StrictData` language extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/StrictPragma).

Comment: @Carl, I think there's likely sense to the bangs on the text fields, but not so much sense to the lack of bangs on the other fields. Bangs on text fields *may* avoid retention of `String`s converted to `Text` somewhere. Since the other fields seem unlikely to be bottom, and also unlikely to be expensive to calculate, they should probably be strict too.

Comment: Similar question: [*Advantages of strict fields in data types*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8576795/2751851)

Comment: @dfeuer: Could you put your comment as an answer to this question? Thanks!

Comment: [All About Strictness](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/09/all-about-strictness) is an excellent article with regard to the topic